# utils.c:38:16: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘double’)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, indexing

I am trying to figure a way to retrieve a specific element from a pointer 3d array in C in the manner of element[i][j][k].

My current approach looks like this:

```
void printElement(double *inputMatrix, int i, int j, int k) {
  double val = *(*( (inputMatrix + i) + j) + k);
  printf("%f\n", val);
}
```

However, if I call printElement(), I am getting the following error:

```
utils.c:38:16: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘double’)
```

What is wrong with the stars?

Comment: Please show how you're calling this function, as well as the definition and assignment of any parameters passed to it.

Comment: If `inputMatrix` is a `double*`, then `(inputMatrix + i)` is `double* + int`, so it's a `double*`. Then you add `j`, which is `double* + int` which again produces a `double*`. And then you apply `*` to it, and `*` applied to `double*` is a `double`. Then you add `k`, so you have `double + int` which is `double`. And then you apply `*` to the whole thing, but you cannot apply `*` to `double`.

Comment: If you want to access`element[i][j][k]` then perhaps write `element[i][j][k]` rather than an equivalent but human-unreadable multilevel pointer arithmetic expression. Of course there is no 3d array anywhere in sight so neither expression is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you actually need more arguments than just the required index. In general, when you are storing a N-dimensional matrix as a linear array, you need the sizes of the matrix along all 2 to N dimensions (all dimensions accept first) to access an element.

For 1D matrix, N-1 is 0. So you just need the index. The code for that is:

```
void printEle(double *mat, int i) {
    double val = *(mat + i);
    printf("%lf\n", val);
}
```

For 2D matrix, N-1 is 1. So along with two indices, you need size of the second dimension. The code for that is:

```
void printEle(double *mat, int N, int i, int j) {
    double val = *(mat + N*i + j);
    printf("%lf\n", val);
}
```

Continuing on, for 3D matrix, N-1 is 2. So the proper code in this case is:

```
void printEle(double *mat, int N, int O, int i, int j, int k) {
    double val = *(mat + N*O*i + O*j + k);
    printf("%lf\n", val);
}
```

However, if you know values of M, N, O in compile time, you can simplify as:

```
void printEle(double mat[M][N][O], int i, int j, int k) {
    double val = mat[i][j][k];
    printf("%lf\n", val);
}
```

If you only know N and O, then also it can be written as:

```
void printEle(double mat[][N][O], int i, int j, int k) {
    double val = mat[i][j][k];
    printf("%lf\n", val);
}
```

After [VLAs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-length-arrays-in-c-and-c/) introduced in C99, even without knowing M, N, O in compile time, you can simply write as:

```
// dimensions must be passed before the array itself
void printEle(int M, int N, int O, double mat[M][N][O], int i, int j, int k) {
    double val = mat[i][j][k];
    printf("%lf\n", val);
}
```

Also, on a sidenote, format specifier for `double` is `%lf` and not `%f`.

Comment: For printf, `%f` works for `double`. It's impossible to pass a `float` to `printf`. (You may have gotten it confused with `scanf`, where `%f` does mean `float*`.)

Comment: @RaymondChen My mistake, yes, `%f` works for `double`. I looked it up.